# What is pitch stability in cars?

Tags: aerodynamics, car

Can reduction in pitching moment of a car be referred to as improved pitch stability?

Or is this term strictly only with regards to aircrafts?

Comment: I suggest that the moment is what causes pitch.  You can reduce pitch without changing the moment.  Resistance & recovery to pitch would be what I would call stability.  Whatever the opposite of a short wheelbase Jeep is.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [wiki regarding pitch stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_static_stability) in aircraft, the terminology generally refers to the tendency of an aircraft to not diverge along the lateral axis when the stable configuration is slightly changed. That is to say, a level aircraft can be nosed over (pitch down) which will result in the aerodynamic forces causing the nose to raise itself, barring any additional external input. The same applies to nose-up forces.

One can certainly reference a pitching movement for a motor vehicle, but such movement is counteracted by suspension and suspension dampers, not aerodynamic controls or forces.

In the automotive world, the terminology of which I am most familiar is "braking induced dive" which refers to the nose of the motor vehicle dipping when braking is applied. Stability is not usually a term applied to this action.

Comment: There is also pitch stiffness, which is the moment change associated with a static change in pitch.

Comment: Then, what's the difference between roll stiffness and roll stability?

Comment: Are you asking for the difference between roll stiffness and roll stability in an automobile? Are you excluding aircraft references with this second question? New questions require new posts.

Comment: Yes I am referring to automobiles. And yes I am excluding aircrafts. If you could please answer it here, it would be helpful.